# Sinking heat from resistors?

Tags: pcb, resistors, heatsink

I'm new to PCBs and I'm working on a project in which I'm dropping ~22.8V across a resistor. I'm using 0.5W resistors (they'll be dissipating about 0.43W with my application). In my prototypes the resistors get fairly warm, and I'm wondering if a heat sink wouldn't be a bad idea. Additionally I could end up with up to 5 of these resistors and if several are on at once, it concerns me that they'd be able to overheat each other. What's the best way to sink the heat off of these guys? Would a [something like this](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0555/9445/products/bp-heat-sink-05a_2048x2048.jpg?v=1407192059) be appropriate?

Comment: I have very rarely seen any resistor not being used as a kind of dummy load having a heatsink. Have you thought about upgrading to 750mW or even 1W resistors?

Comment: Work? Yes. Appropriate? No. Get a suitable rated resistor from the start.

Comment: Factor in cost of heat sink vs 1W resistors.  Go with larger power rating resistors.  More surface area = cooler.

Comment: Or put two twice the size in parallel or better two half the size in series.

Comment: @Trevor Why would two half values in series be better than two double values in parallel?

Comment: @marcelm two in series protects you from a failure in one or the other. If they were in parallel, the one remaining takes the full load.

Comment: Actually first thing to do is re-evaluate your design to see if you can redesign that part no not waste so much power...

Comment: @Trevor Ah, fair point. Although I'd argue it depends on the situation :)

Comment: @marcelm always :)

Comment: Are they through-hole or SMD resistors?  Are there any heat-sensitive parts near the resistors?

Comment: No heat sensitive parts near the resistors. They're through hole. No real reason I can't use 1W resistors, that seems like a good way to go.

Comment: @Brennan Remember to mount them a little bit off the PCB to get a chance of more air flow around them. You can get little ceramic tubes (standoffs) for the leads if you feel the need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember the power rating of resistors is a maximum rating. 0.43W for a 0.5W resistor is a bit close to the edge.

Now, SMD resistors conduct heat well into their pads, and if the pads are connected to a large copper area (like a ground or power plane) then this will suck the heat away and spread it, using the board as a heat sink. In this case, a 0.5W resistor used at 0.43W will be warm, but not close to its maximum temperature.

Thus, if one side of your resistors is connected to a ground/power plane, things will get easier.

Several resistors of lower rating in parallel spread the heat better, too, since you can connect them all to the copper plane. You can also wire them in series, but then only one will be connected to the copper plane.

Another strategy if you use multilayer and have a ground plane on layer 2 is to use wide pads. Since the prepreg between layers 1 and 2 is thin, heat will tend to flow through it and into the ground plane where it is spread around the board, which then acts as a heat sink.

Vertical boards get a lot better convection cooling than horizontal ones.

Comment: ROFL.  I was just going to post 0.43W for a 0.5W is too close.

Comment: would vias provide additional cheap thermal dissipation?

Comment: vias don't dissipate heat but they can transfer it to the nearest copper area (possibly on the other side)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insightful answer. Is there any reason (aside from cost) that 2 0.5W resistors in parallel is a bad idea? i.e. is it necessary to drop that rating for some reason? Seems safer to err on the side of caution and leave them at a higher rating.

Comment: 2x 0.5W resistors is fine, in fact it's better than 1x1W resistor, since it will spread the heat over a larger area, and thus dissipate better into the air.

Answer (score 3):

To dump heat from resistors, do this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuC9ZI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are computations supporting the previous diagram

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL0dhX.png)</sup>

Your heat flows are always constrained by the Thermal Resistance of copper foil; 70 degree Centigrade per watt PER SQUARE of foil is rating of the foil thickness of the standard 1 ounce/foot^2 PCB foil.

A single via, with periphery 1/16" and height also 1/16", is ONE SQUARE of foil; we'll assume the plating process succeeded in depositing 35 microns of copper inside that 1,500 micron (1/16") diameter drilled hole.

And 1cm by 1cm of foil..........is one square, if the heat is uniformly entering one edge and flowing through the (1.4 mil thick, or 35 micron) foil and exiting the opposite edge.

And 10cm by 10cm of foil.........is one square. If the heat is uniformly entering and exiting opposite edges.

Thermal behavior is (somewhat) predictable. Its not magic.

Comment: A small detail with adding a copper area as heatsink is that the c/w reduction doesn't scale linearly. For example: adding another 10 mm2 might be insignificant. The best solution is to add trough hole components nearby.

Comment: Using the Vias to suck up heat, thru the FR-4 from the hot resistor?